# My consultation with volley in android does not return anything

Tags: java, android, rest, web-services, android-volley

I have a function that should return a list with all the objects that I have in a webservice made in php, for this I am using php, but it is the first time I use webservices, and I am a bit lost, the fact is that I am doing the consultation with Volley, I saw some examples, I read the documentation, but this code still does not return anything, I thought it could be the list with the final prefix, but it returns the empty list, this is the code of the function:

```
public  List<Artist> getArtist() {

    final List<Artist> artistList= new ArrayList<>();
    String ip= "http://192.168.58.2:8089/ArtistBCV/consultArtists.php";
    Log.v("url",ip);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ip,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //hiding the progressbar after completion
                try {
                    Artist artist=null;
                    //getting the whole json object from the response
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    //we have the array named hero inside the object
                    //so here we are getting that json array
                    JSONArray heroArray = obj.getJSONArray("artistas");

                    //now looping through all the elements of the json array
                    for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {

                        artist= new Artist();
                        JSONObject jsonObject=heroArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.v("TESTO",""+jsonObject.optInt("id_artist"));
                        artist.setId_artist(jsonObject.optInt("id_artist"));
                        artist.setName_artist(jsonObject.optString("name_artist"));
                        artist.setDeathDate_artist(jsonObject.optString("deathDate_artist"));
                        artist.setBirthDate_artist(jsonObject.optString("birthDate_artist"));
                        artist.setBiography_artist(jsonObject.optString("biography_artist"));
                        artist.setPortrait_artist(jsonObject.optString("portrait_artist"));
                        artist.setPortraitIndividual(jsonObject.optString("portrait_individual"));
                        artistList.add(artist);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.v("ERIRRIRIRIRIRI",""+e.toString());
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    );

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //adding the string request to request queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    Log.v("!!!!!!!SIZE!!!!!!!!!", ""+artistList.size());

    return artistList;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not answerable.  It boils down to *why* your server is apparently giving you no results.  We can't tell you that ... without some more evidence; e.g. error messages, stacktraces, server-side log messages, etcetera.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, I really do not know if it is a bug related to my problem, the thing is that there is no exception in runtime could share, the whole process performed in the console, specifically in the run tab, is in the Answers section, given its extension.